# This is where her heartfulness come into picture. come to the picture ! what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

i don't know the meaning of come into the picture. for example : 
This is where her experience come into picture.

Answer (score 2):

'To come into the picture', means that someone or something that was previously not important within a particular context, relationship, problem or issue, etc., has now become important, and may even now be a central figure. For example:

1. I have been dating Mary for several weeks, and felt that our relationship was blossoming. Recently, Mary was introduced to Harry, and I now feel that she is becoming more interested in him than me. So, I could say, 'My relationship with Mary was going well, until Harry **came into the picture**.'
2. Tom and Sandra had a great marriage, until Tom started gambling and lost their life savings. Sandra might say, 'We had a great marriage, until Tom's gambling **came into the picture**.'

There are several phrases that can be used instead of 'come into the picture', but they all mean essentially the same thing, a new participant has become part of an ongoing activity, relationship, enterprise, etc., which has lead to changes that at least one of the previous participants is not happy with. Some other common phrases you may hear are:

> stepped into the picture
>
> came into play
>
> entered the picture

Note 1: You may also hear a similar phrase, **'no longer in the picture'**. This means the exact opposite of the above, i.e., someone, or something, that was previously an important part of something is no longer considered to be important. For example;

John was one of the main contenders to get a new managerial position at his place of work. Then, it was found out that John had misused company property, so he is no longer in contention for the job. We can say that, 'John is no longer in the picture to get the new managerial position.'

Note 2: Another similar phrase, but with a slightly different meaning is, **'keep someone in the picture.'** This usually means that someone has been given responsibility for doing something, but there is someone else to whom they must provide updates on the progress, or otherwise, of that matter. For example, your boss may say, 'Fred, you have the running on the new Henderson project, but make sure you keep me in the picture.'